# Why can't Selenium IDE be run headlessly?

Tags: selenium, rspec, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Converting over to Ruby/RSpec/WebDriver and spending hours on really tedious things like button-clicking and scrolling. I'm looking back on our old regression suites that we used to run with the IDE, and finding myself super impressed with how solid of a tool Selenium IDE is.

So my question: why can't Selenium IDE be run headlessly somehow? I know this sort of belies the whole idea of an IDE, but I'm really surprised FireFox (or someone else) hasn't built in this feature to make the IDE more of a robust tool.

If this question is too vague, tell me why and I can be more specific.

Comment: I think it is possible: take a look at their tests for example (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/ide/main/src/content/tests/functional) - they kind of doing exactly that. But if you think IDE tests are more stable than Java/C#/Ruby, then you should probably review how your tests/framework/library is organized, what kind of error handling you have, etc. For example I don't have much overhead maintaining 1000+ selenium tests, because we invested in proper decoupling of functional level (application feature) from actual page interaction (managing xpaths and so on).

Comment: Stability is not really a huge concern. We've done a pretty good job of making them durable, so there's little maintenance. As far as the GitHub link, what am I looking at? Not sure how this relates.

Comment: In those tests they are testing selenium IDE using selenium IDE itself + custom extensions for selenium IDE. So they show you how to load selenium IDE automatically, how to get it to load specific tests, etc. So you could use the same method for creating your own headless runner. For instance take a look at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/ide/main/src/content/tests/functional/OpenSeleniumIDE-test.html - it shows how simple HTML page on load loading selenium ide programmatically, that's already a way to do headless run

Comment: And then https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/ide/main/src/content/tests/functional/TestTestRunner-test.html shows you how to load specific script into IDE and get it to run it

Comment: Looks like the best bet for running a bunch of Selenium IDE scripts (HTML files) headlessly is via Selenium RC Server, which takes your HTML files and wraps them into a JavaScript program called 'Selenium Core', which is injected into the browser. Source: http://www.guru99.com/introduction-webdriver-comparison-selenium-rc.html